# Circular Slider - stop rotation at 360 degrees

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a slider that I would like to stop rotating after 360 degrees. My goal would be once the user hits 360 degrees, I would display a custom text option for them.

The issue i'm currently having right now is it stops at my designated value (in this case I just set the slider to stop at 200), but what's happening is it's going past the designated value. For example it jumps to 203, 259, etc. It's not stopping at the value accurately.

Any advice would be great!

```
   struct CaloriesCircularSelector: View {
    @State var calorieValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var angleValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var isDragging = false
   @State private var stopGesture = false
    @State var prevCalorieValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    @State var movingForward = false
    @State var movingBackwards = false
    
    let config = ConfigCircular(
                minimumValue: 0.0,
                maximumValue: 999.0,
                totalValue: 1000.0,
                knobRadius: 15.0,
                radius: 125.0)
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.red)
                .frame(width: config.radius * 2, height: config.radius * 2)
                .scaleEffect(1.2)
             
          
            
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: calorieValue/config.totalValue)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 15)
                .frame(width: config.radius * 2, height: config.radius * 2)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            
            Circle()
                .fill(isDragging ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                .frame(width: config.knobRadius * 2, height: config.knobRadius * 2)
                .padding(10)
                .offset(y: -config.radius)
                .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(Double(angleValue)))
                .gesture(
                   DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.2)
                       .onChanged { value in
                           isDragging = true // Set isDragging to true when the user starts dragging
                         
                           
                       }
                       .onEnded { _ in
                           isDragging = false // Set isDragging to false when the user stops dragging
                       }
               )
            
            Text("\(String.init(format: "%.0f", calorieValue)) cals")
                            .font(.system(size: 50))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
        }
        .onChange(of: self.calorieValue) { newValue in
                   
            
            // Check if the user is moving forward or backward, can't find a use for this right now
                       if newValue > prevCalorieValue {
                           movingForward = true
                           movingBackwards = false
                           print("Moving forward")
                       } else if newValue < prevCalorieValue {
                           movingForward = false
                           movingBackwards = true
                           print("Moving backward")
                       }
                       prevCalorieValue = newValue
                }
        
    }
    
    private func change(location: CGPoint) {
        // creating vector from location point
        let vector = CGVector(dx: location.x, dy: location.y)
    
        let angle = atan2(vector.dy - (config.knobRadius + 10), vector.dx - (config.knobRadius + 10)) + .pi/2.0
        
        let fixedAngle = angle < 0.0 ? angle + 2.0 * .pi : angle
       
        let value = fixedAngle / (2.0 * .pi) * config.totalValue
       if value >= config.minimumValue && value <= config.maximumValue {
           if angleValue >= 200 && value > calorieValue {
               // stop increasing the calorie value if it is already 200 or greater
               return
           }

           calorieValue = value
           angleValue = fixedAngle * 180 / .pi
       }
       
    }
}

struct ConfigCircular {
    let minimumValue: CGFloat
    let maximumValue: CGFloat
    let totalValue: CGFloat
    let knobRadius: CGFloat
    let radius: CGFloat
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to observe the changes in `calorieValue` using `.onChange`.
Here is how to do it.

```
struct CaloriesCircularSelector: View {
    @State var calorieValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var angleValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var isDragging = false
    @State private var stopGesture = false

    @State private var showSlider: Bool = true // Added a new boolean to control when to show the slider

    let config = ConfigCircular(
                minimumValue: 0.0,
                maximumValue: 999.0,
                totalValue: 1000.0,
                knobRadius: 15.0,
                radius: 125.0)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: config.radius * 2, height: config.radius * 2)
                .scaleEffect(1.2)


            if(showSlider) { // Conditionally show or hide the circles responsible for the slider
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.0, to: calorieValue/config.totalValue)
                    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 15)
                    .frame(width: config.radius * 2, height: config.radius * 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))

                Circle()
                    .fill(isDragging ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: config.knobRadius * 2, height: config.knobRadius * 2)
                    .padding(10)
                    .offset(y: -config.radius)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(Double(angleValue)))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.2)
                            .onChanged { value in
                                // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT, ONLY call `change` IF AND IF self.calorieValue is less than 360.
                                if !stopGesture && self.calorieValue < 360 {
                                isDragging = true // Set isDragging to true when the user starts dragging
                                    change(location: value.location) // << controls movement of knob
                                }

                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                isDragging = false // Set isDragging to false when the user stops dragging
                            }
                    )
            }

            // This is really up to you but I decided to add the textfield above the current text that shows the calorieValue 
            VStack(spacing: 10) 
                // Pay attention I am using the variable `showSlider`
                if(!showSlider) {
                    TextField("Enter Calorie", value: self.$calorieValue, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .border(Color.green)
                }

                Text("\(String.init(format: "%.0f", calorieValue)) cals")
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
        // Finally, this is the important bit that will define when to show the textfield and when to hide it and show the slider
        .onChange(of: self.calorieValue) { newValue in
            if newValue >= 360 && self.showSlider == true {
                self.showSlider = false
                self.isDragging = false
                self.stopGesture = true
            } else if(newValue < 360 && self.showSlider == false) {
                self.showSlider = true
                self.stopGesture = false
            }
        }
    }

    private func change(location: CGPoint) {
        // creating vector from location point
        let vector = CGVector(dx: location.x, dy: location.y)

        let angle = atan2(vector.dy - (config.knobRadius + 10), vector.dx - (config.knobRadius + 10)) + .pi/2.0

        let fixedAngle = angle < 0.0 ? angle + 2.0 * .pi : angle

        let value = fixedAngle / (2.0 * .pi) * config.totalValue

        if value >= config.minimumValue && value <= config.maximumValue {
            if angleValue >= 359 {
                stopGesture = true
            }
            else{
                stopGesture = false
            }
            calorieValue = value
            angleValue = fixedAngle * 180 / .pi
          }

    }
}

struct ConfigCircular {
    let minimumValue: CGFloat
    let maximumValue: CGFloat
    let totalValue: CGFloat
    let knobRadius: CGFloat
    let radius: CGFloat
}
```

Please read the comments in the code as they will help you and guide you through it. Also note this code is not perfect as the moment you put any value in the `textfield` will cause it to show the slider if the value drops below 360. As I am not sure of the final behaviour this was left out for you to figure out how you want it to be.

Also note if I were you, I would break down my view into subviews for example I would do

```
...
var slider: some View {
// Put the slider code here
}
...
```

Finally, you may want to add some animations. You can either do it inside `.onChange` using `withAnimation()` or directly call `.animation(.linear, value: self.showSlider)` on the view you want to animate.

Comment: Still having the issue when it hits the calorie value, in your case 360 - once it hits that value you are unable to go back to a lesser value. Once it hits the value, would like to go back on the slider, not remain paused if that makes sense.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I 100% understand what you mean but let me double check. Do you want it to hit 360 calorie value or when the rotation angle hits 360?

Comment: Understandable thank you for looking into. I edited my code, was able to get it to stop and go backwards. BUT the issue I'm currently having is it's not stopping accurately at my inputed calorie value. If I set the value to let's say 200, if I drag the knob, it'll end up going to 205, 240, etc.

Comment: @Swink I tried the code you edited but I can't get it to work now anymore. The knob wouldn't want to move; However, what you are experiencing is a normal behavior because of the delay. A solution to this problem is you can use clamping the values. If the value is greater or equal to `200` then clamp it to 200. Otherwise let the slider take care of it.

Comment: @Swink also I should mention, you can use the `angleValue` instead of `calorieValue` and it should also work. By defining a max value to the slider and checking when the angle is more than `360` or equal to `360` is also a good idea. Since an angle of 360 would also = to the max calorie the slider can handle. I am just not sure about the exact behaviour you are looking for, but this should be a good enough start. feel free to ask if you need any more help.

Comment: added a gif to show the behavior. Notice I set the angle around 200, but the calorie value jumps to different values. The desired behavior would be paused at the same value (ie always stopping at 206 calories)